# Chrome extensions - chrome.tabs.query showing chrome-extension:// as URL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tabs

I'm making my first Chrome extension, which I want to get the URL of the current tab you are on and let you change just the domain/hostname.

E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/help-me-please => https://test.stackoverflow.com/questions/help-me-please

My problem is while trying to debug with the console, I am only able to get it to load for the chrome-extension:// tab, so attempting to use `chrome.tabs.query` with the params of `active` and `lastFocusedWindow` true does not give me where the extension is currently active, `https://stackoverflow.com/`.

Example code:

```
chrome.tabs.query(
  {
    'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function (tabs) {
    var url = tabs[0].url;
    var domain = url.hostname;
    console.log(domain);
  });
```

Is there a way to get my console/debugging to display that URL so I can properly debug? I'm currently running it as an Unpacked extension. I assume that is why I'm getting the extension page instead of the desired URL. Or is there a way to set the params to make it get the correct URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone stumbles across this and makes the same mistake I made, you get the desired URL by right-clicking on your extension icon and clicking `Inspect Popup`.